# Excel: Select Worksheet dynamically (Without sheet name)

Tags: excel, vba

The sheets inside my Excel file are dynamic. I have a button that creates a sheet with it's new name.

Is it possible to select a worksheet in dynamic way? Or without knowing the names of the sheets.

*Here's my vba code for printing a specific range of cells*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("-32628").Select
    range("A1:BZ18").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:BZ18"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut from:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
      :=True
End Sub
```

What I want is to select the `Sheetname: -32628` without putting the actual name of sheet?

Answer (score 3):

> I have a button that creates a sheet with it's new name.

If you are creating a sheet in a button click then it is pretty simple. Declare a worksheet object on top of your code so that it can be accessed by other procedures and then work with it. For example

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:BZ18"

        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut _
        from:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "-32628"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all [Avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). This slows down your code a lot and is a very bad practice.

Instead reference your worksheet directly eg instead of `ActiveSheet`:

```
Worksheets("-32628").PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:BZ18"
```

---

There are 3 ways to reference a worksheet:

1. By its visible tab name

   ```
   Worksheets("YourSheetName")
   ```
2. By its tab position

   ```
   Worksheets(1) 'first sheet in tab list
   ```
3. By its VBA name

   ```
   Sheet1 'note that 1 is not the position of the sheet in the tab list. It's just a name.
   ```

---

- Note that the VBA name of the sheet can be changed in the *Properties* window of the VBA-Editor.
- Also note that `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `Worksheets(1)` and `Sheet1` can be 3 completely different worksheets. I recommend not to use numbers and give them distinct names as the numbers can easily cause confusion.